# In embedded map - can I temp disable all hoverwindows while any infowindow is open

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, carto, infowindow

I have CartoDB map with hover and infowindows for 1000 polygons.
When user click we want to open infowindow for processing (update able form)
and want: stop hover windows from working until user finishes and closes infowindow
Then: re-enable all hover windows...

In embedded CartoDB map - can I temp disable all hoverwindows while any infowindow is open

Answer (score 1):

got it basically:

```
if (is_opened == true) {
    $(".cartodb-tooltip").hide();
}
```